# Why do I need to shuffle data, when I get the path to images?

Tags: neural-network, dataset, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
train_image_paths = [str(path) for path in list(train_path.glob('*/*.jpeg'))]
random.shuffle(train_image_paths)
```

Above is a sample code you can see.

I have the same question in this case too:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(64).shuffle(10000)
```

I don't understand why I need the shuffle in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the obvious case, shuffling is helpful if your training data is sorted by class labels. By shuffling, you allow your model to "see" a wide range of data points each belonging to different classes in the context of classification. If the model goes through a sorted training data, your model runs the risk of overfitting to certain classes. In short, shuffling helps reduce variance and ensures that the train, test, and validation sets are representative of the true distribution.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Since I am getting the filenames, I don't want it ordered in the list because then the model will learn from the ordered list. It was a bit confusing because I haven't worked with images before and just couldn't see the picture right. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Yana Yes, that is the correct understanding. Glad I was able to help.